# Streamlit image not being updated

Tags: python, websocket, streamlit

I am pretty new to the Python world and Streamlit, and trying to set up a small app with Streamlit that connects to a websocket and updates the image on every message. I have the following two files implemented:

```
import websockets
import asyncio
import streamlit as st

from PIL import Image
from util import consumer    

st.set_page_config(page_title="stream", layout="wide")

status = st.empty()
connect = st.checkbox("Connect to WS Server")

placeholder_image = Image.open('placeholder.png')
image = st.image(placeholder_image)

if connect:
    asyncio.run(consumer(status, image))
else:
    status.subheader(f"Disconnected.")
```

And the util file:

```
import io

import websockets
import json
import base64

from PIL import Image
import streamlit as st

WS_CONN = "ws://localhost:8765"


async def consumer(status, image):
    websocket = await websockets.connect("ws://localhost:8765")
    status.subheader(f"Connected to websocket!")

    async for message in websocket:
        current_image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(base64.b64decode(json.loads(message)["image"])))  # until here it works fine, sample log is <PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=1280x720 at 0x129D81FD0>

        image.image = current_image # image is not being updated
```

The current issue is that the image is not being updated when I am trying to set it inside the websocket message handler. Is there something I'm doing wrong within the Streamlit API here? Perhaps some caching issue?

Answer (score 0):

The only place you are plotting the image in the app is at the following lines:

```
placeholder_image = Image.open('placeholder.png')
image = st.image(placeholder_image
```

The image `placeholder.png` is not being updated as far as I can tell.

Please do `st.image(image_from_consumer)`.